# Make Windows Detect Nvidia hardware, BIOS has already detected

Tags: windows-10, bios, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently purchased a GT 710, after plugging it in my computer, i got a black screen but after checking out a youtube tutorial i was able to resolve the issue. The BIOS now detects two graphic cards, it says Intel HD graphics and Nvidia HD Graphics. Windows does not detect the Nvidia Graphic card after booting.

I got a video signal out of the Afox GT 710 graphic card via VGA, and it is where am typing this.  Now how do i make windows detect this hardware?
I have already enabled the card in BIOS.

Comment: If you're getting output, then Windows is detecting it. What's in the _Device Manager_? A screenshot with display adapters expanded would be ideal.

Comment: @gronostaj, it only shows Microsoft Basic Display adapter

Comment: okay, but i have enabled multiple display when am using a single monitor in the BIOS video settings. Can that be the cause?

Comment: https://imgur.com/JJ3CrIX

Comment: Give us the `VEN_` and `DEV_` of the _Microsoft Basic Display Adapter_. _Properties_, then _Details_ and _Hardware IDs_.

Comment: okay, right away

Comment: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_128B&SUBSYS_000010DE&REV_A1
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_128B&SUBSYS_000010DE
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_128B&CC_030000
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_128B&CC_0300

Comment: @gronostaj, the ven an the dev i have suipplied, what is wrong, you ain't feedbacking

Comment: is this graphic card compatible with windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" is your GT 710. The VEN & DEV match that model. Windows gives it a generic name because it's using a generic driver.

Windows Update should pick up drivers for that GPU automatically. Press *Check for updates* and let it do its job.

if you insist on downloading the drivers manually from [NVIDIA's driver download website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/drivers/). The latest driver is the [466.47 release from May 18](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/drivers/results/175537/).

Comment: what about the part where the driver says no nVidia hardware found?

Comment: I dont think so because in BIOS, Its been identified as nVidia HD Grpahics alongside the intel HD graphics. Windows should use the same name it picked from BIOS like the intel HD graphics

Comment: I don't know which driver you were installing. Did you try the one I linked? How about Windows Update? Your assumption that Windows copies the name from BIOS is incorrect. The adapter name is determined by the driver. It happens to match for HD Graphics because you have the right driver installed for it, but not for 710 because it's currently using the generic driver.

Comment: when a driver is scanning for hardware, does it check the BIOS or the system?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about this, but I think Windows is copying it from the INF file when installing the driver based on VEN and DEV identifiers. Anyway, it doesn't have to match anything. In particular it can be completely different from what BIOS reports.

Comment: @CodeTiger Windows reads the VEN_ and DEV_ values from the PCI tables and matches that against a list on known values. From that list it then gets teh information what driver to use. Bios has nothing to do with this at all. You must have downloaded the wrong NVidia driver.

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU GRONOSTAJ, and may you live long enough....
It worked my friend......Am playing this game at crazy FPS .....Whoooooooooooooooo

Comment: Yeah the name has changed from microsoftto nVidia

Comment: This guy Gronostaj is the man......